# Implementing one to many LSTM/RNN, PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I have a matrix sized m x n, and want to predict by 1 x n  vector (x at the [picture with the network structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKlOb.png)) the whole next (m-1) x n matrix (y^{i} at the picture), using RNN or LSTM, I don't understand how to implement feeding each
1 x n vector to the next hidden state and get all the
(m-1) x n vectors simultaneously and how to compute error over all y^{i}

I have this vanilla RNN-model and don't know how to modify it

```
class RNNModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, output_dim):
    super(RNNModel, self).__init__()
    
    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim

    
    self.layer_dim = layer_dim

    
    # (batch_dim, seq_dim, feature_dim)
    self.RNN = nn.RNN(input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, batch_first=True, nonlinearity='tanh')
    
    
    self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)
    

def forward(self, x):
    # Initialize hidden state with zeros
    h0 = torch.zeros(self.layer_dim, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim).requires_grad_()

    
    out, h_t = self.RNN(x, h0)
    
    #out = self.fc(h_t[:, -1, :]) 
    out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :]) 
    
    return out
```

Answer (score -1):

Stainley, try this:
you initiate hidden state only if no other hidden state is passed. then you return the hidden state and pass it to `forward()` at the next iteration.

```
def forward(self, x, h=None):
    
    if h is None: # if no hidden state is passed
        h = torch.zeros(  # Initialize hidden state with zeros
            self.layer_dim, x.size(0),
            self.hidden_dim).requires_grad_()

    out, h_t = self.RNN(x, h)
    out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :]) 
    return out, h_t
```

in training code you run the cycle like this like this:

```
x = seed 
h = None
for i in range (...)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    ...
    x, h = model.forward (x, h)
    ...
    loss = ...
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```